# rails undefined method status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is a very easy question I am using devise for authentication...So I am trying to modify my sign up .I am trying to add a radio button on my sign up but it is giving me error .**undefined method `status' for User:0x00000001a66368**. So i want to know why i can't use radio button on my sign up page 
[registration/new.html.erb]

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :password %> <% if @validatable %><i>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</i><% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>


      <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

        <div >
            <%= f.label 'InActive' do %>
                    <%= f.radio_button :status,'In Active'%>
            <% end %> 
        </div>


      <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

[user.rb]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
      has_many :posts
      has_many :comments

  validates :status,presence:true
  validates :name, presence: true 



  def self.find_role(id)
    User.find(id).roles
  end   


end
```

Comment: Do you have `status` column in `users` table?

Comment: no sir i don't have status column

Comment: Do you wish to save the status field in the database?

Comment: yes i want to add status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rails generate migration add_status_to_user status:boolean
rake db:migrate
```

You need to by pass Strong Parameters to add additional new attributes to the sign up page.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:status)
  end
end
```

Comment: but i don't have a devise controller i only have devise views in my project

Comment: getting error private method `permit' called for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x00000004c114a8>

Comment: This is not the issue. The OP doesn't have `status` column in `users` table.

Comment: @Pavan Well he would have encountered this error any ways after adding the status column to the database.

Comment: not working do  i need to add a status column in my database?

Comment: Of course you have to :) You need to run a migration.

Comment: type of column should be string ?

Comment: No, it should be boolean.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add status field in the user table.

```
rails g migration add_user_status_to_user user_status:boolean
rake db:migrate
```

Then , In application controller, use strong parameters

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:user_status]
  end
end
```